# Simple Web Server on Android

Tags: android, apache

I want to create a simple HTTP Web Server on my Android device. I successfully did that using the org.apache.http library (HttpService class), and it is working fine.

But all around Google keeps saying that this class is deprecated and use HttpUrlConnection instead. I can see that HttpUrlConnection is for connecting to remote server, not hosting a web server locally. Is there any class that Google provides for achieving what I need? If not, then why deprecate the apache library? I think there must be some way to do it without relying on non-supported components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any class that Google provides for achieving what I need?

There is no Web server built into Android. Hosting any sort of server on a mobile device is a risky proposition, given that mobile devices tend to be mobile and get connected to mobile data providers and random WiFi networks. Beyond that, there are lots and lots of things that are not built into Android, such as APIs for controlling dishwashers.

> If not, then why deprecate the apache library?

Because it is an unmaintained fork.

> I think there must be some way to do it without relying on non-supported components.

Find and use a third-party library. [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync) is the one that I have used for embedding Web servers for diagnostic purposes. Or, if you prefer to use Apache's `HttpService`, use their official up-to-date copy.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted to hear,